# Checking and changing JLabel states from another window in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I've got two windows, utilizing two separate classes. My main one has layered JLabels holding images that I would like to be able to use the setVisible command to toggle them back and forth with checkboxes I have in my second window. I used windowbuilder to create the windows and the visual elements, so the code gets a little confusing to me. I've tried making a setter and a getter, but eclipse keeps telling me "Syntax error on token "boolean", @ expected" which hasn't been helpful. Perhaps I've been up way too long, but I can't figure out if I'm putting the getters and the setters in the right spot. Here's some of the code for my main window.

```
public class ChristmasTree {

private JFrame frame;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ChristmasTree window = new ChristmasTree();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                ControlWindow.createWindow();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}



/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ChristmasTree() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(200, 50, 500, 625);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(layeredPane, Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 484, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(1)
                .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 561, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    JLayeredPane backGround = new JLayeredPane();
    backGround.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
    layeredPane.add(backGround);

    JLayeredPane treePane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setLayer(treePane, 0);
    treePane.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
    layeredPane.add(treePane);

    JLabel treeLabel = new JLabel("");
    treePane.setLayer(treeLabel, 0);
    treeLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChristmasTree.class.getResource("/resources/tree.png")));
    treeLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
    treePane.add(treeLabel);



    JLayeredPane decorationsPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setLayer(decorationsPane, 2);
    decorationsPane.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
    layeredPane.add(decorationsPane);
    decorationsPane.setVisible(true);


    JLabel starLabel = new JLabel("");
    starLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ChristmasTree.class.getResource("/resources/star.png")));
    starLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
    decorationsPane.add(starLabel);
    starLabel.setVisible(false);
```

for instance, this starLabel here - I want to use a checkbox to toggle it back and forth from visible == true/false.  I don't know if this will help, but here's part of the code for the second window.

```
public class ControlWindow extends ChristmasTree {

private JFrame frame;
private boolean isSnowSelected = false;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void createWindow() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ControlWindow window = new ControlWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ControlWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(700, 100, 455, 231);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ChristmasTree myChristmasTree = new ChristmasTree();

    JLabel chooseLabel = new JLabel("");
    chooseLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ControlWindow.class.getResource("/resources/message.png")));

    final JCheckBox chckbxSnow = new JCheckBox("Snow");
    chckbxSnow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (isSnowSelected == false)
            {   

            }
            else if (isSnowSelected == true)
            {

            }

            if (isSnowSelected == true)
            {
                isSnowSelected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isSnowSelected = true;
            }
        }
        });
```

the whole isSnowSelected boolean I was planning on doing something else, but if I can just get a returned boolean, I could write it so much easier. Any ideas? By the way, I'm really grateful for everybody that continually reads questions like mine, it's nice to know there's somebody who actually cares.

Comment: Consider using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for toggling.

Comment: Basically, you need a reference to your main window in your child window and some way then for the child window to communicate it's desires to the child window.  What I could consider doing is having some kind of model instead, which both windows had a reference to.  The main window would listen to changes to the model while the child window would tell it what changes it wanted made.  This decouples your UI and prevents the child window from doing things with the main window that it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Both windows have no linkage in your code. You need to have a `reference` of the Main window in the `Child` window to set the `Checkbox` property of the Main window during the firing of `actionPerformed()` Method. The best way is to create a `Delegate` Class between the Main and Child window which will the do the **enable/disable** operation of `Checkbox`. In addition to that, you have just the `frame` reference in the `Class` level and all the other Components are in the `method` level. In order to change the properties of the components in a window, you need to declare them in the `Class` level. Please create `setters` and `getters` for all the components of the windows. That will really help. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a static variable for the status of check box (to show or to hide)
that will be access by class name that will show you current status of visibility of label.

```
public class ABC {

public JFrame frame;
private static boolean isSnowSelected = false;
private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
JLayeredPane backGround;
JLayeredPane treePane;
 JLayeredPane decorationsPane;
 JLabel starLabel;
JLabel treeLabel;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ABC window = new ABC();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                ABC window1 = new ABC();
                window1.frame.setVisible(true);
                ControlWindow.createWindow();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ABC() {
    initialize();
   runth();
}
public void runth(){
    Thread th = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            if (isSnowSelected) {
                                treeLabel.setVisible(true);
                                starLabel.setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                treeLabel.setVisible(false);
                                starLabel.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                };
                th.start();
}
public static boolean getSelected() {
    return isSnowSelected;
}

public static void setSelected(boolean value) {
    isSnowSelected = value;
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    try {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(200, 50, 500, 625);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(layeredPane, Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 484, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(1)
                .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 561, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        backGround = new JLayeredPane();
        backGround.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
        layeredPane.add(backGround);

        treePane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setLayer(treePane, 0);
        treePane.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
        layeredPane.add(treePane);

         treeLabel = new JLabel("");
        treePane.setLayer(treeLabel, 0);
        treeLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ABC.class.getResource("/resources/tree.png")));
        treeLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
        treePane.add(treeLabel);



        decorationsPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setLayer(decorationsPane, 2);
        decorationsPane.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
        layeredPane.add(decorationsPane);
        decorationsPane.setVisible(true);


         starLabel = new JLabel("");
        starLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ABC.class.getResource("/resources/star.png")));
        starLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 484, 586);
        decorationsPane.add(starLabel);
        starLabel.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ControlWindow extends ABC {



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void createWindow() {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ControlWindow window = new ControlWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ControlWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    try{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(700, 100, 455, 231);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    final JCheckBox chckbxSnow = new JCheckBox("Snow");
     frame.add(chckbxSnow);
    chckbxSnow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           if(chckbxSnow.isSelected()){
               setSelected(true);
           }else{
               setSelected(false);
           }
        }
    });
}catch(Exception Ex){
      Ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code that helps you to resolved your issue. Here in the example, if `MainFrame's` `JCheckBox` is selected than it will also set `OtherFrame's` `JCheckBox` selected.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

        private OtherFrame c = null;
        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();

        public MainFrame() {
            addActionListener();
        }

        public void setC(OtherFrame c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        private void addActionListener() {
            checkbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //performs operation
                    if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
                        c.checkbox.setSelected(true);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class OtherFrame extends JFrame {

        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();

        public OtherFrame() {
            addActionListener();
        }

        private void addActionListener() {
            checkbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //performs operation
                }
            });

        }
    }
```